# Unable to sync gradle android studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-emulator, adb

```
Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.AbstractKotlinGradleModelBuilder'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I have tried updating platform tools still it is not working. Few days back it was working fine I don't understand what happened suddenly.

Also while running emulator it is showing ***Unable to locate adb*** but emulator runs even after showing that error.

[image][image]

Comment: Click on this **Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)** when you are connected with internet.

Comment: I have a stable network, Also few days back it was working fine. I have re-downloaded still same error @MdAman

Answer (score 0):

Try to update kotlin plugin by going through these steps :

```
Double shift -> Plugins -> Updates -> Search Kotlin -> Update! -> Restart Android Studio
```